# How to add data to CSV columns, one by one using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas script as follows. Where I am reading multiple csv files in a given folder. All the csv files have a similar format and columns.
For a given column(Area), I want to add all the rows. Then I want to save this data into a new CSV file.

This is the code so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\kundemj\Desktop\Post_Processing\HEA517_2000' # path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    area_sum = df['Area'].sum()
    print(area_sum)
```

I could figure out, by using excel_write function, but I want to use 'to_csv', and also with mode = 'append', as I have bunch of folders with same filenames.

The CSV file format I am looking for is as follows:

```
filename1, filename2, filename3,.....
area_sum1, area_sum2, area_sum3,.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\kundemj\Desktop\Post_Processing\HEA517_2000' # path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

# Create an empty dict
results = {"filename": [], "sum": []}

# Iterate on files and populate the newly created dict
for filename in all_files:
    results["filename"].append(filename)
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    results["sum"].append(df['Area'].sum())

# Save to csv file
results = pd.DataFrame(results)
results.to_csv(path="path_to_file.csv", index=False)
```